# I need to merge cells in a table. Exceljs library

Tags: javascript, jquery, exceljs

There was a problem.
I create worksheet in library EXCELJS

```
function save_export(){


    var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('sheet', {
      pageSetup:{paperSize: 9, orientation:'portrait',fitToPage: true,fitToHeight :  99 , fitToWidth :  1, horizontalCentered: true}
    }); 

    var tfoot = [];

        $(element).each(function(index_tfoot, element_tfoot) {
          $($(element_tfoot).find("#tfoot tr")).each(function(index_tr, element_tr) {

                $(this.cells).each(function(index_td, element_td) {
                    tfoot.push($(element_td).text());   
                });

                var row_foot = worksheet.addRow(tfoot);
                row_foot.eachCell(function(cell,rowNumber) {

                    cell.font = { name: 'Verdana', size: 11};
                    cell.alignment = {horizontal: 'center' };
                    cell.border = {
                      top: { style: "thin" },
                      left: { style: "thin" },
                      bottom: { style: "thin" },
                      right: { style: "thin" }
                    };


                    <!-- if(cell._value.model.value === 'ИТОГО'){ -->
                        <!-- var c = 'A'; -->
                        <!-- var r = cell._row._number; -->
                        <!-- var sum = c+r; -->
                        <!-- worksheet.mergeCells(sum + ': B31'); -->
                    <!-- } // ПОЛУЧИЛ ИТОГО -->

                });

                tfoot = [];

                });
        });

    });




        workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(function (data) {
            var blob = new Blob([data], {
                type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            });

            saveAs(blob, "Исходная выборка.xlsx");
        });
```

};

when I merge cells, my merged rows over cells as in the screenshot "before". You see what number 238 disappear.

I need the cells to move.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyquZ.png - before
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DeRc.png - after

How we see in screenshots, cells merge and value ​​disappear ((

need to shift(

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem.The data needs to be added after merging the cells. Please refer the documentation https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#merged-cells

Comment: Please post relevant parts of the code directly here and not just link to another page.

Comment: @Homungus Refer the below code to know how I handled as per my app requirement. 
`code`
    let titleRow = worksheet.addRow([]);
    let currentRow = titleRow._number;
    // merge by start row, start column, end row, end column
     worksheet.mergeCells(currentRow,1,currentRow,12);
     let titleCell = worksheet.getCell('A'+currentRow);
     titleCell.value = "title_text";

Comment: Hi, i am facing a similar issue where i am using `addRow` to copy rows from excel to another excel, the merged rows capabilities seems to be lost though. The rows does not have cells merged as in source excel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65320644/addrow-not-adding-merged-cells-correctly-which-are-read-from-source-file do you know what could be the issue here?